# How to have the DXA config files references outside of the DXA.ear for different environments (ST,PT,DEV) in DXA 1.5?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

We are using the DXA Java 1.5 implementation with 2013 SP1 and need to have the references for the resource files (`cd_dynamic_conf.xml`, `cd_link_conf.xml`)  outside of the war. Is there a way to do it?

This will help us to avoid maintaining different repos.

Comment: I think you might find an answer faster by ignoring the "DXA" part of your question and figuring out how your app server supports this.

Comment: Did you find any way of doing it? I am too looking for a solution to above problem.

Comment: @Abhi I did not have have luck with this . Please let us know if you have made progress

Comment: No, nothing at our end too. We use 3 different branches for 3 different environments and in each branch the above file has different property.